# Javascript Mootools click event and his caller?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, mootools, javascript-framework

I have this little script:

```
var moolang = new Class({
    initialize: function(element) { 

        this.el = $(element);
        this.el.addEvent('click', this.popup);  

    },

    popup: function()
    {
        //this.id = the id of the element.
    }
});
```

And I want to know "this" in the popup function, but if I try something like `alert(this.el.id)` it says there is no this.el.

Is there a way to know which class adds the event?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the attach event so the callee has the proper context. Otherwise the context of an event listener will be the target element.

```
// Change this line
this.el.addEvent('click', this.popup);
//To this
this.el.addEvent('click', this.popup.bind(this)); // popup->this == this
```

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/N2FcV/1/) 
See mootools [documentation](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Types/Function). Binding the context of a function.